# Why does Eclipse insist on a package name for an Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Brand new Android developer here, also new to Eclipse.

I downloaded and installed

- JDK
- Android SDK
- Eclipse for Java
- then downloaded and installed into Eclipse the Android ADT Plugin

All installed successfully -- I did this yesterday (7/14/11) so I have the latest of all.

In Eclipse, I select 'New Project' and I select 'Android->Android Project' for the project type.

I then get to the new project window in Eclipse and it wants 3 things:

1) Project name -- DONE.  I name my very first Android project "myAndroidOne"

2) I select the 'Create new project in workspace' radio button

3) I select 'Android 2.2' for the 'Build target'

4) I accept Eclipse's suggestion for the 'Application name', "myAndroidOne"

I have no idea what Eclipse wants in the 'Package Name' field.  Although I'm aware of 'Java packages,'
it confuses me that Eclipse might want me to specify a Java package here -- after all, I'm
creating a new project and have zero idea, being brand new to Android, what if any Java package I will
be using.

I tried entering "pkgMyAndroidOne" but the 'Next' button does not light up.

I cannot create a brand-new Android project -- I have not written a single line of code, I just wanted to create an Eclipse Android project to start teaching myself how to write my 1st Android app.

What is Eclipse wanting here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is Android itself requires package names in order to run the app.

Just create a name like "wantTheBest.playground.firstapp" as the package name and you should be fine.

If you were to release the app on the market, the package name would be used in updating the app.  It's essentially permanent at that point.

Comment: I specified mynew.pkg.myAndroidOne as the package name then Eclipse enabled the 'Next' button, but the next window forced me to create a 'test project' or the project creation would not continue.  How would I then create a 'real', non-test project then?

Comment: Just click "finish" next time.

Comment: It shouldn't force a test project. Just unclick "Create a Test Project" at the top, and hit finish.

Comment: Sheesh I'm such a deuce.  I re-did a new project and instead of selecting 'Next' I just clicked 'Finish' and Eclipse no longer coerced me into creating a test app.  Thanks.  As usual, all the responses I received here are great and helpful yet I have to 'accept' only one, so I apologize in advance, I very much appreciate everyone's help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Packages are typically named using the following convention:

[org/com].[company].[product].[component]

Some choose to drop the first segment, so it would be:

[company].[product].[component]

By convention, package names should not contain capitals.

Answer (score 3):

It needs to be something like com.mypackage.testapp 
This might help you - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 2):

The package name will also give you uniqueness on Android market. Two packages cannot be uploaded with the same name. All Android Market Urls will be also generated out of the same convention.

To be easily distinguishable on Android Market... its required.

Answer (score 2):

The convention for java packages is the reverse of a websites order (IE com.companyname.applicationname) The reason why this is so important is because there may be multiple applications on the market with the same name (flashlight) so package name uniquely identifies the application (com.pyrodante.myflashlight). Once created and signed, both the application and the jarsigner key are locked. To change either causes the Android Market to think it is an entirely new application.